# k8s nginx ingress controller: rewrite part of the target url

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a way to create an ingress rule that modifies part of the target url? Something like routing `/v1/api/service_name/endpoint` to `/endpoint`? I am using nginx ingress controller on GKE.

Comment: `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"` works if the ingress rule is `/v1/api/service_name`. However if the ingress rule is the whole url (`/v1/api/service_name/endpoint`) I cant find a way to just strip the last part of the url (`endpoint`).